# Passing variable to getElementById()

Tags: javascript, json, dom, getelementbyid

I must be overlooking something simple here. I cant get `getElementById()` to act on the variable passed to it.

```
function newforminput() {
     var jsonstring = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('jsonobj').innerHTML);
     var numfields = jsonstring.tracelog.fields.length;

     for (var i=0; i<numfields; i++){
         var field = i+jsonstring.tracelog.fields[i].name;
         if (jsonstring.tracelog.fields[i].dependantfield != "---"){
             document.getElementById(field).readOnly = true;
         }
         console.log(field);
     }
}
```

`console.log` returns the correct ID of the div i want to affect, but the console tells me `document.getElementById(field)...` is null.  Why is it not receiving the variable?

I'v seen a lot on this, but nothing seems to be working for me.

console.log(field) renders "1SectionName" - or whatever else its required to.  If the element wasnt created yet, wouldn't the error be `document.getElementById(1SectionName)...` is null? That is, if the variable was being passed.

Comment: can you post your markup as well?

Comment: If it returns `null`, the element with that ID doesn't yet exist.

Comment: can you please post the element markup and also the content of var "field"?

Comment: the table containing the input element is created in PHP, on the server.  the function above is called from a window.onload event.  should i post the code from "view source" to see the rendered code, or the pre processed PHP?

Comment: As cookie monster said, if the function returns `null`, then either you are calling the function too early (doesn't seem to case here) or the element with that ID really doesn't exist. Not much else we can do about it.

Comment: Logically, this wouldn't mean anything else but have you tried moving your `var field` declaration line inside the `if`?
I know that doesn't make much sense but my colleague ran into similar problem back in the day and that is how he solved it.
I don't know what that happened but giving it a try wouldn't hurt, now would it?

Answer (score 0):

you were so right.  A syntax error was prohibiting the id of the element from being created, so no element of that id existed hence the null error.  Sorry for wasting your time due to a syntax error, but your input certainly helped me analyze my code more intelligently.  Thanks for not ridiculing seemingly simple mistakes (as i often witness elsewhere) and providing meaningful insight for us newbies.  thanks again!!!